# How do I change the keyboard input language on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10

I've tried adding a preferred language and choosing the new language in the language bar but the input still comes out in English. Is there anything else I need to do?

[image]

Clarification: I want to be able to type in Korean but it keeps coming out in English.

Comment: What input are you referring to exactly. Clarify your question by editing it

Comment: @Ramhound I want to be able to type in Korean but it keeps coming out in English.

Comment: When you select Korean from the list of display languages what happens?

Comment: It shows the Korean icon in the taskbar but when I type, it still comes out in English.